# Split given array to a new array on the basis of specific field of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having array like this.

```
$arrr = [
    95 => ['title' => 'CONTACT US', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 95],
    100 => ['title' => 'CUSTOMER SERVICE', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 100], 
    105 => ['title' => 'SHOPPING TOOLS', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 105], 
    126 => ['title' => 'COMPANY INFO1', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 126], 
    108 => ['title' => 'COMPANY INFO', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 108], 
    111 => ['title' => 'CONNECT WITH US', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 111], 
    114 => ['title' => 'OUR OTHER SITES', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 114], 
];
```

Now i want array like this.

```
$arrr = [
    0 => ['title' => 'CONTACT US', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 95],
    1 => ['title' => 'CUSTOMER SERVICE', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 100], 
    2 => [
        0 => ['title' => 'SHOPPING TOOLS', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 105],
        1 => ['title' => 'COMPANY INFO1', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 126],
        2 => ['title' => 'COMPANY INFO', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 108], 
    ],
    3 => [
        0 => ['title' => 'CONNECT WITH US', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 111], 
        1 => ['title' => 'OUR OTHER SITES', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 114]
    ]
];
```

OR

```
$arrr = [
    95 => ['title' => 'CONTACT US', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 95],
    100 => ['title' => 'CUSTOMER SERVICE', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 100], 
    105 => [
        105 => ['title' => 'SHOPPING TOOLS', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 105],
        126 => ['title' => 'COMPANY INFO1', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 126],
        108 => ['title' => 'COMPANY INFO', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 108], 
    ],
    111 => [
        111 => ['title' => 'CONNECT WITH US', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 111], 
        114 => ['title' => 'OUR OTHER SITES', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 114]
    ]
];
```

Given array having a field "break". On the basis of this field "break", array has to be split as shown in resultant array.

Please share solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can one *possibly* know that `126` and `108` are supposed to belong to `105`, yet `100` is not supposed to belong to `95`? There's nothing to indicate how the arrays should be grouped. I would *guess* you're trying to split on `break`, but you appear to have both `0` and `1` in 105. Please update your question to **clearly** state how the arrays should be split, and how that is determined.

Comment: what have you tried so far , also I see break = 0 and 1 combined , isn't this intriguing

Comment: The element having break 1 will be a separate element in another array and array having break 0 will be another array in that separate array having next element, if next element having again break 0 then it should be come in that separate array untill next element having break = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Giving yon answer for first array....

```
<?php
    $arrr = array(
        95 => array('title' => 'CONTACT US', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 95),
        100 => array('title' => 'CUSTOMER SERVICE', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 100), 
        105 => array('title' => 'SHOPPING TOOLS', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 105), 
        126 => array('title' => 'COMPANY INFO1', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 126), 
        108 => array('title' => 'COMPANY INFO', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 108), 
        111 => array('title' => 'CONNECT WITH US', 'break' => '0', 'id' => 111), 
        114 => array('title' => 'OUR OTHER SITES', 'break' => '1', 'id' => 114), 
    );
    $new_array = array();$i=0;
    foreach($arrr as  $row){
        if($row['break']==1){ if(!isset($new_array[$i]))$new_array[$i] = $row;else $new_array[$i][]=$row;$i++;}
        else $new_array[$i][] = $row;
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Result

```
    Array(
        [0] => Array([title] => CONTACT US, [break] => 1, [id] => 95),
        [1] => Array([title] => CUSTOMER SERVICE, [break] => 1, [id] => 100),
        [2] => Array(
            [0] => Array([title] => SHOPPING TOOLS, [break] => 0, [id] => 105),
            [1] => Array([title] => COMPANY INFO1, [break] => 0, [id] => 126),
            [2] => Array([title] => COMPANY INFO, [break] => 1, [id] => 108),
        )
        [3] => Array(
            [0] => Array([title] => CONNECT WITH US, [break] => 0, [id] => 111)
            [1] => Array([title] => OUR OTHER SITES, [break] => 1, [id] => 114)
        )
    )
```

Comment: I have tried this solution.                                                                        
$result = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($arrr as $key => $value) {
 $result[$i][] = $value;
 if($value['break'] == 1) {
  $i++;
 }
}
echo '<pre>';
//print_r($result);